# Nested IF functions in excel with blank cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Checked through a few other questions and can't see the same issue. Perhaps I am approaching this from the wrong angle. Any help or advice appreciated.

I have a worksheet which contains contact details, and a second worksheet which reformats these to be imported into a 3rd party system. I am using a column containing 'X' to pick out those to be migrated. My issue comes when people have provided a home number and no mobile number or vice versa, for the import to work all numbers must be in the same column, so I need to nest a second IF function which asks subsequently, if the cell is blank, go to the next cell.

Essentially merging these two statements (below)? - But not sure how!

`=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X",'Master contacts list'!H10, IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",'Master contacts list'!J10))`

Perhaps I should use multiple logical statements instead, but can't get my head around this either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, you want your second IF statement to be in the `true` parameter of the first `if()` statement so it reads "IF this cell contains "x" then do this next if statement. Next If statement: If the home phone is blank, then use the mobile number otherwise use the home phone number"

This looks like:

```
=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X", IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",'Master contacts list'!J10, 'Master contacts list'!H10,), "")
```

Comment: Thanks saved me such a headache, ultimately tweaking what you have stated the final formula looked like this:

`=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X", IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",'Master contacts list'!J10, 'Master contacts list'!H10))`

(in case anyone searching has the exact same problem)

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk through the logic. IF we are supposed to copy this data (`"X"`), and IF there is no home number (`=""`), copy the cell number. ELSE IF there is a home number, copy the home number.

I find it helps to put the various levels of logic on separate lines and indent them so I can understand which ones depend on which. So

```
=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X", IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",'Master contacts list'!J10, 'Master contacts list'!H10), "")
```

So if we reformat this on multiple lines

```
=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X",     IF I am supposed to copy this data
   IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",      IF the home phone number is empty
     'Master contacts list'!J10,            Copy the mobile number
   'Master contacts list'!H10),           ELSE Copy the home number (since the cell is not empty)
 "")                                    ELSE make this cell blank (since we weren't supposed to copy the data
```

So scenario 1: There is no "X"

```
=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X",     IF I am supposed to copy this data
   IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",      IF the home phone number is empty
     'Master contacts list'!J10,            Copy the mobile number
   'Master contacts list'!H10),           ELSE Copy the home number (since the cell is not empty)
 "")  <<<<<<                            ELSE make this cell blank (since we weren't supposed to copy the data
```

Scenario 2: There is an "X" and there is a home phone number

```
=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X",     IF I am supposed to copy this data
   IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",      IF the home phone number is empty
     'Master contacts list'!J10,            Copy the mobile number
   'Master contacts list'!H10),<<<<<<     ELSE Copy the home number (since the cell is not empty)
 "")                                    ELSE make this cell blank (since we weren't supposed to copy the data
```

Scenario 3: There is an "X" and there is no cell phone number. This one is a bit of a hack because if we don't have a cell number, we know that we only got to this logic because we didn't have a home number, so we'll just copy the cell number by default. If it's a blank cell, our new phone column will be blank too.

```
=IF('Master contacts list'!M10="X",     IF I am supposed to copy this data
   IF('Master contacts list'!H10="",      IF the home phone number is empty
     'Master contacts list'!J10,<<<<<<      Copy the mobile number
   'Master contacts list'!H10),           ELSE Copy the home number (since the cell is not empty)
 "")                                    ELSE make this cell blank (since we weren't supposed to copy the data
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Amazing. Breakdown. Thank you. Great way to approach nested forumula.